# Setting the div height to proportional of the width of the background

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've created this slider through a bootstrap however there seem to be something wrong with the height when u resize the browser it does not adjust the size of the div. How can i set the div height to be proportional with the width? And how can i add this to a wordpress page. i've tried to add the bootstrap files, but not seem to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/bn6aA/36/

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

        </ol>   
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                    <p class="center lead league-name">Liga BBVA</p>
                    <div class="row center">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="http://demo.themeum.com/sportsline/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/151.png" alt="Barcelona">
                            <strong>Barcelona</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p class="score">3 - 1</p>
                            <p class="datetime">16 Feb 2014</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="http://demo.themeum.com/sportsline/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/131.png" alt="Granada">
                            <strong>Granada</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


.item {
padding: 60px 20px;
color: #fff;
background: url('http://charlieintel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/IMG_2372-620x400.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
    font-size: 52px;
    text-align: center; 
}



.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-control{
    top: 50%;
}
.bs-example{
    margin: 20px;
}
.carousel-control {
    left: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 100;

    background: #222;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
    -moz-border-radius: 23px;
    border-radius: 23px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 margin-top: -20px;   
}

.league-name {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}

.lead {
font-size: 21px;
}

.row {
}

.col-xs-4 {
float: left;
}

 img {
margin: 10px 0;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
}

strong {
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
}

.score {
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 20px;
}


.datetime {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: use percentage widths - i.e. `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a fixed margin on the .item class. The elements inside are not adjusting it's size, and that keeps the slider responsive in the width but not the height.

This is the best solution I found right now. There are probably better adjustments, but this seam to work ok.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/exc8snpx/4/

Edit your CSS:

Add:

```
.myCarousel {padding-top: 10%;
padding-bottom: 10%;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-right: 5%;}
```

Edit:

```
.item {
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-top:8%;
    padding-bottom:8%;
    color: #fff;
}
```